# Tie the sending of an ajax request to Wordpress hooks

Tags: ajax

I'm tracking events on my site such as login & registration and need to send an AJAX post when these events occur.

I've explored ways to do this from the frontend, but have determined that the only accurate way would be to tie the event directly the a hook.

Extra points: I need to include a value from a javascript object unique to each user (or guest).

Any creative ideas?

Comment: Have you looked into the wp_ajax hooks?

Comment: @Welcher - Doesn't that work the opposite way? Having an event detected by JS, and then sending that to the WP backend.

Comment: I think I misunderstood - you're wanting to trigger an ajax call from another action?